# VC++ undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why this in Client.cpp file I'm getting error C2065:'TunnelContainer': undefined identifier?

Client.cpp code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GClientLib.h"

using namespace GClientLib;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   SettingsReader^ settings = gcnew SettingsReader();
   SocketToObjectContainer^ STOContainer = gcnew SocketToObjectContainer();
   TunnelContainer^ tunnels = gcnew TunnelContainer();

   timeval time;
   time.tv_sec = 0;
   time.tv_usec = 300000;
....
```

GClientLib.h code fragment:

```
 #include "Structures.h"
 #include "Globals.h"
 #include "SettingsReader.h"
 #include "SocketToObjectContainer.h"
 #include "SocketToSocketContainer.h"
 #include "TunnelContainer.h"
```

Updated. SocketToSocketContainer.h

```
#ifndef SocketToSocketContainer_H
#define SocketToSocketContainer_H

#include <cliext/utility> 
#include <cliext/list>
#include <cliext/algorithm>

namespace GClientLib {
    ref class SocketToSocketContainer {
        private:
            cliext::list<cliext::pair<int, int>> sarasas;
        public:
            SocketToSocketContainer(void);
            void Add(int, int);
            int Find(int);
            void Delete(int);
    };
};
#endif
```

GclientLib is lib project, used in Client application. Build on Visual Studio 2013 C++/CLI enabled

## TunnelContainer.h code:

```
#ifndef GClientLib_H
#define GClientLib_H

#include <cliext/utility> 
#include <cliext/list>
#include <cliext/algorithm>

namespace GClientLib {
    enum TunnelStatus
    {
        JUNGIASI = 1,   //Uzmezgamas rysys tarp klientu
        LAUKIA_PROGRAMOS = 2,   // Laukia kol prisijungs norima kliento porgramine iranga
        KOMUNIKACIJA = 3    // Tuneliu vyksta komunikacija
    };

    ref struct Tunnel
    {
        int tag;        //Tunelio zyme
        int dport;      //Prievadas, prie kurio jungesi
        int clientid;   //Kliento ID su kuriuo sujungta
        int sport;      //Vietinis prievadas
        int serverSocket;   //Socketas, prie kuris priima duomenu srauta
        int status;     // Sujungimo statusas (Jungiasi, prisjungta, laukia jungties)
    };

    ref class TunnelContainer {
    private:
        // Tuneliu sarasas
        cliext::list<cliext::pair<int, Tunnel^>> sarasas;
    public:
        // Konstruktorius
        TunnelContainer();
        // Pridedamas naujas tunelis. PERRASO statusa i JUNGIAMASI
        Tunnel^ Add(Tunnel^ tunelis);
        // Pridedamas naujas tunelis. Statusa nustato i JUNGIAMASI
        Tunnel^ Add(int tag, int dport, int clientid, int sport, int serverSocket);
        // Tunelio paieska pagal tag
        Tunnel^ Find(int tag);
        // Salina tuneli pagal tag
        Tunnel^ Remove(int tag);
        // Keicia tunelio statusa
        void ChangeStatus(int tag, TunnelStatus status);
    };
};
#endif
```

## UPDATE

After moving TunnelContainer.h into first position getting this error in ToServerSocket.h file:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^' line 16
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int line 16
```

ToServerSocket.h code:

```
#ifndef ToServerSocket_H
#define ToServerSocket_H

#include <iostream>

#include "gNetSocket.h"
#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "OutboundSocket.h"

namespace GClientLib {
    ref class ToServerSocket : public gNetSocket {
        private:
            char *commandBuffer;
line 16 --->TagGenerator^ tag; 
            SocketToObjectContainer^ STOC;
            SettingsReader^ settings;
        public:
            ToServerSocket(string ip, string port, fd_set* skaitomiSocket, fd_set* rasomiSocket, fd_set* klaidingiSocket, SocketToObjectContainer^ STOC, SettingsReader^ settings);
            virtual int Send(char* data, int lenght) override;
            virtual void Recive(SocketToObjectContainer^ container) override;
            virtual void Connect() override;
            virtual void Reconnect() override;
            void CommandList(int page);
            void CommandListAck(int rRecv);
            void CommandHello();
            void CommandHelp();
            void CommandInitConnect(int id, int port, SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandConnect(SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandClear();
            void CommandBeginRead(SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandClientConnectAck(SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandInitConnectAck();
            void CommandJsonList(int page, SOCKET socket);
            void CommandJsonListAck(int rRecv, SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandJsonInitConnect(int id, int port, SOCKET socket);
            void CommandJSONConnect(SocketToObjectContainer^ container);
            void CommandJsonInitConnectAck();
            int GenerateTag();
    };
};

#endif
```

Comment: In Client.cpp when I type GClientLib suggestions also don't show TunnelContainer, tried event included directly to Cleint.cpp

Comment: [MCVE] as usual please. Otherwise diagnosis isn't possible.

Comment: What does TunnelContainer.h look like?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm code added

Comment: This doesn't look like C++.

Comment: @zenith FYI it is Visual C++

Answer (score 1):

you probably have a syntax error or missing `;` or missing closing `"` in the include before that, `"SocketToSocketContainer.h"`.

`#include` is a precompiler statement, all it does is include the content of the given file into the main file; it is your task to make sure that the result is a valid code. So if one include has an incomplete statement, the content of the second include continues that statement.

Edit: It could be even further up in the list - any open or incorrect #IFDEF in any include could remove the whole rest

Comment: I have posted SocketToSocketContainer.h code. Project builds succeddfully. I haven't found any errors

Comment: I moved TunnelContainer.h include in first position. Error changed. Posting in question

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. GClientLib_H was already defined.

```
#ifndef GClientLib_H
#define GClientLib_H
```

Changed to

```
#ifndef TunnelContainer_H
#define TunnelContainer_H
```

Now everything is working. Thank you for quick responses